# How to use execvp/execlp with environ

Tags: c, exec

How do i set the environ before execlp ?

```
     #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <syslog.h>
//    Tried extern char **environ;

    int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
    {
// Tried environ = -- gives compile error
        char** environ =
        {
            "foo=bar",
            "hello=world",
            0 // zero byte
        };

        //environ = ??
        execlp("env", "env", (char*)0);
    return 0;
    }
```

did not print foo = bar
Thx.

Comment: You don't need to declare environ. It is declared in `unistd.h`. Just populate it

Comment: execvp.c: In function ‘main’:
execvp.c:9:3: error: ‘environ’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   environ =
   ^
execvp.c:9:3: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

Comment: doesnt compile even with unistd.h

Comment: Thx. It erased everything else in the env that was there before :(

Comment: Yeah, I see.. Will look for a more graceful way to populate it...

Comment: I see no other way than iterating until the end of environ and then append elements using pointer operations. There is no variable that shows how many elements are currently stored in environ

Comment: ya, its a pain, Iam thinking of resorting to setenv, since my app takes user env in the form of "myvar=myval;myvar1=myval2..." I better iterate for strtok of ";" and then send it to a func that does setenv("myvar", "myval")

Comment: Or set just the environ values that you need and don't care about the existing env. (I guess that most of the variables in env aren't required by your application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man execlp` and `man environ` will help:

> The execle() and execvpe() functions allow the caller to specify the environment of the executed program via the argument envp. The envp argument is an array of pointers to null-terminated strings and must be terminated by a NULL pointer. The other functions take the environment for the new process image from the external variable environ in the calling process.

`environ` is declared in `unistd.h` as `extern`, you need to populate the variable before calling `execlp()`. Also note that the strings in `environ` are expected in the format `key=value`;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// declare environ as extern
extern char** environ;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // populate environ
    environ[0] = "foo=bar";
    environ[1] = NULL;

    // call execlp
    execlp("/usr/bin/env", "", (char *)0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @H2CO3 Would like to work more with C.. Unfortunately the most things at the job are script related....

Comment: I understand. Personally, I'm yet a freelancer, so I can use my language of choice, which is C :))

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
 int pid;
 char* enviro[1][2] = {{ "myvar", "myval" }};
 printf ("%s=%s \n", enviro[0][0], enviro[0][1] );
 char** environ =
 {
  "foo=bar",
  "hello=world",
  0 // zero byte
 };

 //environ = ??
 execlp("env", "env", (char*)0);
return 0;
}

did not print foo = bar

Comment: @purpletech You should edit your question and do not post this as a comment. (It's unreadable)